# template specialization define in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I declared a template specialization `template <> class Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>`, and defined it.

1. My question is when I reduce the `NullType` in Component, `p->Initialize()` will always success and is called. What is this feature?
2. Another question is why I cannot define both `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` and `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` at the same time?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class NullType {};

template <typename M0 = NullType, typename M1 = NullType,
          typename M2 = NullType, typename M3 = NullType>
class Component {
 public:
  bool Initialize();
};

template <>
class Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType> {
 public:
  bool Initialize();
};

bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize() {
    cout<<"Hello World3";
    return true;
}

// bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize() {
//     cout<<"Hello World4";
//     return true;
// }

int main()
{
    auto p = new Component<>();
    p->Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any error messages when compiling this? If yes, show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is when I reduce the `NullType` in Component

Then the default argument specified in primary template, i.e. `NullType` will be used. As the effect,

```
bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize() {
```

is just same as:

```
bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize() {
```

> Another question is why I cannot define both `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` and `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` at the same time?

As explained above, they're considered as the same and you'll get a redefinition error.

Comment: thx! I still can't understand which template is defined! And the second question is because of template deduced parameter?

Comment: @dahohu527 It's still related to the default argument specified in the primary template. `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` and `bool Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>::Initialize()` are the same thing you just can't define it twice.

Comment: @dahohu527 template's concrete instance with same name and same set of parameters is same type, `Component<>();` and `Component<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType>();` are same type in this case because you defined default template-parameters. But `Component<SomeArbitraryType>();`  would be a different type and there is lack of member function definition to fit it.